# SwiftUI List have a weird transition after navigation presentation

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Here is my structure:

ContentView :

```
{
NavigationView
   List {
      NavigationLink 1
      NavigationLink 2
      NavigationLink 3
   }
}
```

Target With Dynamic list :

```
{
   List {
      ForEach (model.array) {
         NavigationLinks
      }
   }
}
```

i do have a shared @EnvironmentObjet model class with my datas inside

After navigationLink button triggered, when second view appear, my 2nd view's list cell's contents do a little unexpected transition (left & right to center).
Looks like its due to auto layout but i can't understand why it happend and dont know how to fix.

[First screen when 2nd view juste apear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNLrv.jpg)

[2nd screen after that transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhcY1.jpg)